# How to assign DisplayMemberBinding converter in the c# code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, code-behind, ivalueconverter

I have a `GridViewColumn` and I want to assign to its `DisplayMemberBinding` property a converter. I am able to do it in XAML, but I would like to add it from the code-behind for personals reasons.

When I try to assign my converter in the code it says that I need a `IValueConverter` type, but it is an interface and not an object that I can create. I am able to take the converter from an other `GridViewColumn`, but I won't always have the converter that I want assigned to another one.

```
<!-- XAML code that works and that I want to implement in the code-behind -->
<GridViewColumn x:Name="intensityColumnStatus" Header="Intensity" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Intensity,Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />

// Code-behind that I can't get to work
Binding visibilityBinding = new Binding("isPlaneComing");
visibilityBinding.Converter = ???;
```

I know that I'm maybe missing some information, so if you need more, please just ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. 
I was trying to just put

```
visibilityBinding.Converter = myConverterClass;
```

but in reality I needed to simply put

```
visibilityBinding.Converter = new myConverterClass();
```

I hope this can help someone in the future.